# Worklight 6.0 WL development Server not starting

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

**When I try to start my worklight development server Which is running on Windows 8 OS It gives me below error.**

CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
CWWKE0018E: An exception occurred while launching the runtime environment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebSphere-DefaultExtension-windowsnt(unknown)
com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.LaunchException: Caught unexpected exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebSphere-DefaultExtension-windowsnt(unknown)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.rethrowException(KernelBootstrap.java:412)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.go(KernelBootstrap.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.createPlatform(Launcher.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:55)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.cmdline.EnvCheck.main(EnvCheck.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebSphere-DefaultExtension-windowsnt(unknown)
    at java.util.jar.Attributes$Name.(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.BootstrapManifest.getOSExtensionDefinition(BootstrapManifest.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.internal.KernelBootstrap.go(KernelBootstrap.java:122)
    ... 3 more

Can someone please help me on this...

Comment: Hello,

That exception is thrown by WAS before Worklight starts up:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.messages.doc%2Fcom.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.resources.LauncherMessages.html

That document mentions checking the logs to for any other exception. Adding the websphere tag to see if others might be of more help here.

Mike

Comment: Thanks Mike for adding Tag.

Comment: As the link that Mike mentioned suggest, can you add more logs? Please also explain the exact scenario and details - which is your Eclipse version? is this as new project? did you edit something it? is there at all a project, or are you just trying to start the server? is there a project loaded in the workspace?

Comment: Hi Idan I had setup the Worklight environment on my machine and just run a test project that time I was getting this error. I copied the same ellipse environment on to Windows-7 machine where it run successfully. Later I found that we have to install a 64bit eclipse Juno version for Windows 8 64bit OS, Then  my application started without any errors.(WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile)

Answer (score 11):

This is a defect caused by a combination of Java (does not recognize Windows 8) and Liberty (does not handle unknown Windows os.name gracefully), so I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.  As a workaround, you can specify `-Dos.name=Windows 8` in [jvm.options](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html).

Edit: This problem has been fixed in the [V8.5.5.Next Alpha](https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/downloads/websphere-application-server-v8-5-5-next-alpha-liberty-profile/).

Edit 2: This problem is listed as part of APAR [PI26048](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI26048), which is "currently targeted for inclusion in fix pack 8.5.5.4."

Comment: you can add server.env or jvm.options file to your `${server.config.dir}`. It is `${wlp.user.dir}/servers/serverName`. A sample jvm.options file can be found in the link.

Comment: I am using Worklight 6.2 and ran into similar problem (lots of errors on development server's start up). after reading your answer here, I downgraded the JDK used to 7 (instead of 8) and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Please use 64bit eclipse Juno version for Windows 8 64bit OS. The WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile will start without any errors, In the above case.

Answer (score 1):

this is not an IBM issue. its a known bug in the JVM https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7170169.

JVM accidently identifies windows8 as "WinNT" .
either use the jvm.options workaround (to give Liberty a hint of the true OS)
or upgrade your JVM with a better build.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the V8.5.5.Next Alpha.